# Using DENSE_RANK to split up a data set

Tags: sql, t-sql, window-functions

I'm trying to split a dataset with the below so I can assign a value based off of a value from another table.

Here's the code that I've tried so far to achieve this using DENSE_RANK().

```
declare @t1 table (ID char(3) not null,Name char(5) not null)
insert into @t1(ID,  Name) values
('ID1','Test1'),
('ID2','Test1'),
('ID3','Test2')

declare @t2 table (CusID char(3) not null,counter int not null)
insert into @t2(CusID,  counter) values
('A1', 100),
('A2', 200),
('A3', 300)


select ID,Name,'ExampleST' +
       RIGHT('00000' + CONVERT(varchar(4),
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Name)+ counter)
       ,5) as NewID
from @t1
CROSS JOIN @t2
order by ID
```

This returns:

```
ID  Name    NewID
ID1 Test1   ExampleST00101
ID1 Test1   ExampleST00201
ID1 Test1   ExampleST00301
ID2 Test2   ExampleST00102
ID2 Test2   ExampleST00202
ID2 Test2   ExampleST00302
ID3 Test3   ExampleST00103
ID3 Test3   ExampleST00203
ID3 Test3   ExampleST00303
```

What I want it return

```
ID  Name    NewID
ID1 Test1   ExampleST00100
ID1 Test1   ExampleST00100
ID1 Test1   ExampleST00100
ID2 Test2   ExampleST00200
ID2 Test2   ExampleST00200
ID2 Test2   ExampleST00200
ID3 Test3   ExampleST00300
ID3 Test3   ExampleST00300
ID3 Test3   ExampleST00300
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Can you explain the logic you want to implement?  As far as I see, you're `CROSS JOIN`ing on `@t2` which includes the values `100, 200, 300`.  This means that each row in `@t1` will be matched with *all three rows from `@t2`*.  But you're saying that is not what you want?  *(You want `ID1` matched with `100`, but not `200` or `300`?)*  Whether or not you have the window function correct I can't tell, but your desired output definitely contradicts your `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: The CROSS JOIN is used to intentionally create a cartesian product.  ID1 should be linked to the A1, ID2, A2 and so on but it cannot be statically linked so more rows could be inserted to both tables and it would work without changing the script.

Comment: Your Cartesian product, however, is contradicted by your desired output.  Based on the `CROSS JOIN` and the string manipulation in your SQL you ***should*** be getting three ***different*** strings for each row in `@t1`; (`ST001??`, `ST002??`, `ST003??`).  Yet, you want all three strings for each row to be the same?  Why?  Please give a fully functional explanation in English as to the logic you wish to implement.  All I can tell for now is that your example and your SQL contradict each other.  *(Note; none of this has anything to do with `DENSE_RANK()` which is why I seek clarification.)*

Comment: Also, I've noticed that `ID2` should be `TEST1`, but your example output states `TEST2`.  Unfortunately, there are too many discrepancies, and too few details, to be able to establish what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I can see that you've edited the post.  Unfortunately the output still doesn't match the `INSERT` statements *(`ID2` = `TEST1` in the `INSERT`, but in the output it's `TEST2`)*, there still isn't clarity about why `+ count` should give the same result in all three rows with the same `@t1.id` *(rather than one row having `+100`, another having `+200` and the last having `+300`)*, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't want `dense_rank()`, you just want `max()` of the counter for each name:

```
select ID, Name,
       ('ExampleST' +
        right('00000' + cast(dense_rank() over (order by name) * 100 as varchar(255)),
              5) as NewID
from @t1 cross join
     @t2
order by ID;
```

Comment: This would just return ST00300 for all rows which is not right

Comment: @totalfreakingnoob . . . I see what you are saying.  I fixed the logic so I think it does what you want.